# Increment width from right to left using calc on IE

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, microsoft-edge

I have an item that should grow from right to left. It works well in some browsers, but in IE (even Edge) it doesn't work.

The item has a fixed width, but its parent is responsive, and has a sibling that must be absolute positioned to be hidden when the item grows.

I made a snippet to show how it should work (the item is the red one, click it):

The relevant CSS is in child-02:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.child-02').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
h1,
h2 {
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 14px;
}
div {
  border: solid 1px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 40px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  background: rgba(100, 200, 255, 0.5);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.parent {
  min-height: 150px;
}
.child-01 {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(50% - 20px);
  z-index: -1;
}
.child-02 {
  background: rgb(220, 90, 100);
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  margin-left: calc(100% - 150px);
}
.child-02.open {
  margin-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="uncle"></div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-01">
    <h1>There's some text</h1>
    <h2>Here's a bit more</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="child-02">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="aunt"></div>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: make it float to the right, so there is no confusion of where about to stand : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GrKJKj

Comment: It is a known bug of IE. It does not support transitions for `calc` values. See http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli I think my solution fixes the problems IE got with transitions and `calc` (or at least some of them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so sure that you will like this solution, but it works :)

The reason for `IE` to make the animation from Left to Right is that the `direction` of the parent element is `LTR` (**L**eft-**T**o-**R**ight). If you change the direction of the parent to `RTL` - the animation will be as you wish.

The problem here is that this change require you do add a few other CSS things (to make sure nothing breaks).

Here is the final code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.child-02').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
h1,
h2 {
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 14px;
}
div {
  border: solid 1px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 40px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  background: rgba(100, 200, 255, 0.5);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.parent {
  min-height: 150px;
  direction: rtl;
}
.child-01 {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(50% - 20px);
  z-index: -1;
  left: 20px;
  direction: ltr;
}
.child-02 {
  background: rgb(220, 90, 100);
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  margin-left: calc(100% - 150px);
}
.child-02.open {
  margin-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="uncle"></div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-01">
    <h1>There's some text</h1>
    <h2>Here's a bit more</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="child-02">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="aunt"></div>
```

Here are all the changes I made to your CSS:

```
.parent {
  direction: rtl;
}
.child-01 {
  left: 20px;
  direction: ltr;
}
```

Comment: This is such a smart solution! And it works! <3
In my case, it messed up the top and bottom margins. Why? Who knows, but this is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `transform` instead of `margin-left`.

Here's an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.child-02').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
h1,
h2 {
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 14px;
}
div {
  border: solid 1px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 40px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  background: rgba(100, 200, 255, 0.5);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.parent {
  min-height: 150px;
}
.child-01 {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(50% - 20px);
  z-index: -1;
}
.child-02 {
  background: rgb(220, 90, 100);
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  transform: scaleX(.2);
  transform-origin: right;
}
.child-02.open {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="uncle"></div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-01">
    <h1>There's some text</h1>
    <h2>Here's a bit more</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="child-02">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="aunt"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem with scale is that it would distort the text inside (the item has a lot of content).